# Inserting an image in latex document

Tags: graphics

I am trying to insert an image in latex document. But I am getting an error. I am using the following commands with `\usepackage{graphicx}`

```
\graphicspath{ {/Users/richie/Downloads} }
\includegraphics{Log.png}
```

I am attaching my code and error.

[image: Code]
[image: Error]

Comment: Which error do you get? How do you compile your document, with pdflatex or another engine?

Comment: Are you sure you are using pdfLaTeX (or LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX) and not the original LaTeX in DVI Mode? In DVI Mode PNGs are not supported. Please post the error message(s) in question.

Comment: Also `{/Users/richie/Downloads}` doesn't sound that right. You are under MS Windows, right? Try e.g `{c:/Users/richie/Downloads/}`.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer Please see my edited question.

Comment: @samcarter Please see my edited question.

Comment: @prashantsharma Can you show the start of the `.log` file (the yellow window you show us above)

Comment: I believe you may simply be missing the final slash on the path. It should be `\graphicspath{{/Users/richie/Downloads/}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation for `graphicx`, `\graphicspath` expects a list of names in the same format as that required for the LaTeX `\input@path`. As the LaTeX source tells us

> [E]ither dir should be defined as a macro with argument delimited by space,
>   or it should just expand to a directory name, **including the final directory separator**, so that it may be concatenated with the filename. This means that for UNIX-like syntax, each dir should end with a slash, /.

You are missing the final slash in the directory. That at least is one possible reason why the file will not be found. Of course, if you are using Windows you have, as Martin Scharrer pointed out in his comment, another problem too.

Comment: From the screenshots I'd say it is mac and not windows, so I think you nailed the problem

Comment: I thought it was *probably* Mac. I think the documentation of `graphicx` could be improved on this point: it would be more useful for **most** users to simply be told to add the final slash, rather than be left to root around in `source2e` for information about `\input@path` ... especially since the error message does not help much.

Comment: The author of `graphicx` might not have considered the possibility, that people would read the documentation :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an slash / at final part of the path.

This works for me:

`\graphicspath{{/home/rogelioprieto/Downloads/}}`

**for you:**

`\graphicspath{ {/Users/richie/Downloads/} }`

This is an *example* in documentation:

[image]

Comment: Isn't this exactly what the already existing answer by @Paul Stanley said?

Comment: yeah, but when I've read for first time, didn't appeared @Paul Stanley answer!